# MVC route where path exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to create a route that will caption a url like

```
http://mysite.com/tech/
```

but I also have an actual directory under the site that is /tech, which contains other static resources. Not my design choice, but I'm migrating an older site to mvc and dont want to break a bunch of very old links.

My route seems to keep failing, and what I can figure is that the server sees this directory and is trying to serve up the default file from it... but none is found, and it fails.

I'd like it to use my route instead and let me serve up my view. Any best practices for this?

UPDATE: 
I tried using RouteExistingFiles = true, which made this work, but then I had issues with files which existed inside these directories. (for instance: http://mysite.com/tech/image.jpg).  I started adding IgnoreRoute entries for all the various file types that I wanted ignored (ie .jpg files..), but this turned into a big mess. There's gotta be a better way?

Comment: after working more over the weekend, still no solution for this found...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the RouteExistingFiles property of your RouteCollections object to true. This will make your routing override the physical location if a clash is found.

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
    );
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

To selectively ignore files/extensions you can use :

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*staticfile}", new { staticfile = @".*\.(css|js|gif|jpg)(/.*)?" });
```

Another approach which might help if you don't like the `ignoreRoute` approach, is to extend the ViewEngine and override the file exists implementaion with your own rules.

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
    {
        //Some Logic to check for file
    }
}

ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
```

Comment: I found this and gave it a try, but my problem is there are a bunch of static files inside these same folders that I need to have accessible. so, i want the route to fire when hitting /tech, but serve the static file when hitting /tech/image1.jpg.

Comment: so I had to add a bunch of ignoreroute entries for static file types.... and things got really ugly from there.

Comment: You can selectively ignore by file extension if that helps.

Comment: my dislike of this method is that it forces me to add a big list of file types, and will require me adding more in the future if a new type of file is added. secondarily, I'm assuming this could affect performance as well. Is there no way to possibly add a default. aspx file in the directories to catch the request (since it would be in the default file list) and have it hand things back to the view engine?

Comment: How about the custom view engine approach then? I don't know that much about them yet, but looks like it could do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I went with the routes.RouteExistingFiles = true solution.  As a heads up to anybody else that goes with this method, you'll have to add a matching context.Routes.IgnoreRoute() in the RegisterArea method in any areas that you have set up in addition to the routing in the Global.asax.