# ASP.NET MVC routing when a controller's and folder's names are the same

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If a controller, say `FooController`, has the same name as an existing folder, say `/foo`, then what must be done so that requests for http://example.com/foo serve the controller's `Index` view?

**Additional Information**

- Requests for http://example.com/foo should, but are not, returning `FooController's` `Index.cshtml` view.
- Requests for http://example.com/foo return an HTTP 403.14 error. The folder does not have a default document. Directory browsing is not (and should not be) enabled.
- The default routing (i.e., `routes.MapRoute("Default",
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action =
  "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`) is set up and working.
- Requests for other views in the controller, such as `http://example.com/foo/bar work.

**EDIT**

I am leery of using `RouteExistingFiles` based upon what I have read in a number of places (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7216986/2615878) very similar Stackoverflow question). Is another, less severe, option available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC route where path exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216986/mvc-route-where-path-exists)

Comment: @vcsjones - I edited the question to hopefully find a better solution than using `RouteExistingFiles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not name folders and controllers the same name because it causes routing problems. The main problem is when its looking for the view its going to all possible paths that it knows of to find for your `index` in a controller called `foo` but since you also have a folder called foo it apparently found that first and assumed it was in there.  I do not suggest changing the route config in order for your current setup to work.  I would suggest changing the folder name or controller to something else.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. My website is a moderately large, Web Forms website that is incrementally being converted to MVC. Because of this, I will have identical folder and controller names until the site is converted.

Comment: As much as I wish this wasn't the answer, I prefer it over RouteExistingFiles. I will have to gradually eliminate the name collisions on my website.